# Adding oninput space to HTML input form value with JS, not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add automatic spacing of numbers in an HTML input field, with help of javascript, but it seems to be some limitations to the input field itself. I am writing this as a part of a wordpress plugin, so that's why I am escaping ": to use it into the return variable for the plugin output.

So,
I have the basic input field HTML code:

```
      <input class=\"numbersfield\" type=\"numbers\" oninput=\"numberWithSpaces(this.value);\">
```

And here is the function:

```
function numberWithSpaces(x) {
var parts = x.toString().split(\".\");
document.getElementById(\"numbersfield\").value = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, \" \");
```

And it's outputting no spacing in the numbers field. However, when pushing the same data out to a label, the spacing is there: (see also screengrab in the link)

```
document.getElementById(\"lblError\").innerHTML = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, \" \");
document.getElementById(\"numbersfield\").value = parts.join(\" \");
document.getElementById(\"numbersfield\").value = document.getElementById(\"lblError\").innerHTML
```

}

Using this as a number input field, makes the field empty after applying the first space. Changing it to input type text resolves this. At last when I suddenly thought I had it, it gives wrong spacing after the first correct spacing, spacing every new value, like 1 0 0 0 000 000.

Anyone got the grip of this functionality? Any help appreciated!

[screengrab of input form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLoyh.png)

Comment: altering while they are typing is always going to lead to problems.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to achieve the effect like so:

```js
function format() {
    var x = document.getElementById("numbers");
    x.value = format1(x.value);
}
function format1(s) {
    return s.toString().replace(/(?!^)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/gm, '$& ');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numbers"><button onclick="format()">Format</button>
```

If you want to achieve it in real time:

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");
function format() {
    var x = document.getElementById("numbers");
    if(x.value.length>50){
       text.textContent='why so long tho';
    } else {
      text.textContent = format1(x.value);
    }
    
}
function format1(s) {
    return s.toString().replace(/(?!^)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/gm, '$& ');
}
```

```html
Format your text!<br><br>

<input type="text" id="numbers" oninput="format()">
<p id="text"></p>
```

If you want to change it while the user is still typing:

```js
function format() {
    var x = document.getElementById("numbers");
    x.value=format1(x.value.toString().replace(/\s/g, ''));
    
}
function format1(s) {
    return s.toString().replace(/(?!^)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/gm, '$& ');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numbers" oninput="format()">
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. It works in the text field below, but if applied to replace what you're typing in the input field, it is the same issue with creating spaces like for an example 1 1 2 2 1 331, and not 11 221 331. If value is applied to another text input field than the one you're writing in, it's also correct. But for replacing in the same input field as where you're typing, I don't get the correct functionality.